# Semicolon expected in java method

Tags: java, methods, compiler-errors

When I compile this, I get an error stating a semicolon is expected after (String[] args). I can't wrap my head around it. If I do add one, I get 10+ errors unsurprisingly

import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;

public class PayCheck
{

```
private String givenName;      
private double totalWage;
private double totalHours;

private double gross, netPay, tax, ssnTax;    

static String employer="PrismHR"; 
static double taxRate = 0.22;
static double ssRate = 0.06;

public static void main (String[] args) PayCheck()
{  
    Scanner std = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter employee name: ");
    givenName = std.nextLine();

    System.out.println("Enter pay rate and hours worked: ");
    totalWage = std.nextDouble();
    totalHours = std.nextDouble();
    gross = totalWage*totalHours;
    tax = gross*taxRate;
    ssnTax = gross*ssRate;
    netPay = gross-tax-ssnTax;
}

public PayCheck(String name, double wage, double hours)
{ 
    this.givenName = name;
    this.totalHours = hours;
    this.totalWage = wage;

    gross = totalWage * totalHours;
    tax = gross * taxRate;
    ssnTax = gross * ssRate;
    netPay = gross - tax - ssnTax;
}

public String toString()
{
    String emptyString = "";

    NumberFormat formats = new DecimalFormat(".##");

    emptyString += "Employer: " + employer + "\n";
    emptyString += "Employee: " + givenName +"\n";
    emptyString += "Gross income: $" + formats.format(gross)+"\n";
    emptyString += "Federal Tax: $" + formats.format(tax) + "\n";
    emptyString += "Social Security Tax: $" + formats.format(ssnTax) +"\n";
    emptyString += "Net Pay:  " + formats.format(netPay);

    return emptyString;
}
```

}

Answer (score 3):

Oftentimes, and this goes for all programming languages, the error itself may not be accurate. In your case, you have function call just kind of... there.

```
public static void main (String[] args) PayCheck()
{
    ...
}
```

Get rid of `PayCheck()`. I'm not sure what you're trying to do with it, but that is definitely causing the error.

Comment: I think it is an attempt to define a no-args constructor rather than a function call.

Comment: @Ivar I am pretty sure you are right, because if he uses this block as `main` he will still have an error because he is setting non-static class fields from a static context.  I believe the correct fix should be changing it to `public Paycheck()` instead of `main`.

Comment: @Nexevis Changing it to public Paycheck() did indeed work. Grr such a silly error. Thanks!!